# Allow a maven exec during integration-test phase to make the build fail

Tags: java, maven, testing, exec

I've a sniped like the following on my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <phase>integration-test</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>java</goal>
   </goals>
  </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
  <mainClass>com.example.StartTestMain</mainClass>
  <arguments>
   <argument>target/classes/local.testrun</argument>
  </arguments>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

While it executes without problems, I find that return code is ignored and there is no way for StartTestMain to tell the build that it should fail.

I'm thinking about propagating an Exception hoping that maven will take it and stop the build. However, this will fail if exec-maven-plugin is ever configured in forkMode.

Any cleaner options?

Comment: You say the return code is ignored? In other words: if the System.exit code is not 0, the exec-maven-plugin accepts it and succeeds? That would be a bug. Also, please **always** lock the version of plugins, in this case to 1.2.1 and try it again.

Comment: @RobertScholte thanks for your reply. The version is locked in pluginManagement. Regarding your comment, yes, I've checked the maven-exec-plugin code and it should stop. I'll investigate further.